Black duck maven project integration
I am in the process of integrating Black Duck into our CI/CD pipelines. Our tech stack includes Java, Maven, and Gradle for the backend, with React for the front end.
For the Maven project, I am encountering an issue in that mvn clean install is triggered when black duck is performing the scan. Some of the dependencies are hosted in a private repository (jfrog), which is not publicly accessible, causing the Black Duck scan to fail when attempting to resolve these dependencies.
I have added the following stage for Black Duck. Could you please assist with this?
Additionally, is there a way to prevent running mvn clean install during the scan, as it has already been executed in the earlier stages of the pipeline?
I tried to add the seetings.xml file with credentials for my private repository but it seems not to work.
- task: SynopsysDetectTask@9
        displayName: Black duck scan
        inputs:
          BlackDuckService: 'SCAPPS-BLACK DUCK PAT'
          DetectVersion: 'latest'
          DetectArguments: |
            --blackduck.timeout="300"
            --detect.project.name="DMDex-Backend"
            --detect.project.version.name="version:1.0"
            --detect.code.location.name="Dmdex-core-service"
            --detect.accuracy.required="MAVEN"
            --detect.wait.for.results=true
            --detect.maven.build.command='--settings \$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/.m2/settings.xml --define reason=other'

